# Method to pass into Jquery function for initial state (onCreate) but also when a click event is captured

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, survey

I am having difficulty figuring out how to properly fire this function related to the browser events. Currently if I use, for example (my function name is initRanker)

```html
  <row label="r1"><span class="blueRow">Blue</span></row>
  <row label="r2"><span class="redRow">Red</span></row>
  <row label="r3"><span class="GreenRow">Green</span></row>
  <col label="c5" open="1" openSize="25" randomize="0"><span class="blueCol">Blue OTHER</span></col>
  <col label="c6" open="1" openSize="25" randomize="0"><span class="redCol">Red OTHER</span></col>
  <col label="c7" open="1" openSize="25" randomize="0"><span class="greenCol">Green OTHER</span></col>
```

```
  $ (window).load(function() {
   jQuery.onCreate("*",initRanker);           
  });
```

it will work on page load, then break from there. And if I change to:

```
   $ (window).click(function() {
   jQuery.onCreate("*",initRanker);           
    });
```

It will work only when the click event is captured.

I am wondering how to modify this to work for both basically, or to be pointed in the right direction for how to achieve that result.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
function initRanker() {
   if ($ (".blueRow").parent().is(":visible")) {
    console.log("Blue i am visible");
    $ (".blueCol").parent().show();
    $ (".redCol").parent().hide();
    $ (".greenCol").parent().hide();
    $ (".sq-cardsort-bucket-c6").hide();
    $ (".sq-cardsort-bucket-c7").hide();    
  }
  else if ($ (".redRow").parent().is(":visible")){
    console.log("Red i am visible");
    $ (".redCol").parent().show();
    $ (".blueCol").parent().hide();
    $ (".greenCol").parent().hide();
    $ (".sq-cardsort-bucket-c5").hide();
    $ (".sq-cardsort-bucket-c7").hide();    
  }
  else if ($ (".GreenRow").parent().is(":visible")){
    console.log("Green i am visible");
    $ (".greenCol").parent().show();
    $ (".blueCol").parent().hide();
    $ (".redCol").parent().hide();
    $ (".sq-cardsort-bucket-c5").hide();
    $ (".sq-cardsort-bucket-c6").hide();    
  } 
}
     
$ (window).load(function() {
   jQuery.onCreate("*",initRanker);           
});   
     
$ (window).click(function() {
   jQuery.onCreate(".blueRow",initRanker);           
});  
 
$ (window).click(function() {
   jQuery.onCreate(".redRow",initRanker);           
});  

$ (window).click(function() {
   jQuery.onCreate(".GreenRow",initRanker);           
});
```

Comment: `onCreate()` is creating a listener that runs when the `create` event occurs. Adding another listener when you click is probably not what you want. You should just call `initRanker()` directly.

Comment: `$(window).click(initRanker)`

Comment: @Barmar I've updated my function calls. Basically now it works for the first and last row only (or if I go backwards in the cardsort cards then all show properly). If I just use onCreate() itself as above it will still only work for initial page load.

Comment: XML radio question:

<radio 
  label="Q1">
  <row label="r1"><span class="blueRow">Blue</span></row>
  <row label="r2"><span class="redRow">Red</span></row>
  <row label="r3"><span class="GreenRow">Green</span></row>
  <col label="c5" open="1" openSize="25" randomize="0"><span class="blueCol">Blue OTHER</span></col>
  <col label="c6" open="1" openSize="25" randomize="0"><span class="redCol">Red OTHER</span></col>
  <col label="c7" open="1" openSize="25" randomize="0"><span class="greenCol">Green OTHER</span></col>
</radio>

Comment: The Rows show 1 by 1 once a column is clicked

Comment: I've never heard of `jQuery.onCreate()`. Is this a third-party library?

Comment: Don't try to put code in comments, edit the question.

Comment: @Barmar It has been used within the Decipher survey platform "https://forstasurveys.zendesk.com/hc/en-us"

Comment: You should be consistent in your naming style. `GreenRow` should be `greenRow`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to use `onCreate` for both `*` and specific classes. `*` matches anything, so it will run when any element is created.

Comment: @barmer updated with the xml Radio question above. Yes, I was playing around with it but when I only use the first function call, it only works on page load. When I have those multiple calls it works for the first and last row only (and it works for all when going backwards). Which is why I am having difficulty figuring out the actual function calls needed to make it work from the start.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by xml Radio. I'll leave this for someone who knows the Decipher Survey platform.

Comment: @Barmar also here is OnCreate() "https://github.com/eclecto/jQuery-onMutate"